# node.js/angular.js - Cannot GET

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have the root route and it works fine. I also have a another route 127.0.0.1:3000/dashboard if I just type that url into the address bar I get this error:

Cannot GET /dashboard

If I create a link to the same url it works fine.

If I then refresh that page I get the same error again.

Below is my node.js route

app.js

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes  = require('./routes')
  , stats   = require('./routes/stats')
  , tests   = require('./routes/test')
  , http    = require('http')
  , util    = require('util')
  , path    = require('path');

var app = module.exports = express();

app.configure(function(){

  /*
   * Configuration
   *
   */
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  /*
   * Middleware definitions
   *
   */
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  /*
   * Error handling middleware
   */
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('shhhhhhhh, super secret'));
  app.use(app.router);

  // serves up dynamic css files
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));

  // serves a static path
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

});

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});


/*
 * Endpoints
 */
app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/test', tests.get);
app.post('/test', tests.post);
app.options('/test', tests.options);

app.get('/stats/sends', stats.sends.get);
app.get('/stats/events', stats.events.get);
app.get('/stats/attempts', stats.attempts.get);
app.get('/stats/errors', stats.errors.get);
app.get('/stats/mquad', stats.mquad.get);

app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
app.get('/index/landing', routes.landing);
app.get('/index/dashboard', routes.dashboard);

console.log('Env: ' + app.settings.env);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

routes/index.js

```
    exports.dashboard = function(req, res){
        res.render('dashboard');
    };
```

Angular route

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/landing',
            controller: LandingCtrl
        }).
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard',
            controller: DashboardCtrl
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Answer (score 12):

The reason this does not work is that **your server is not catching all other routes** and routing them to your single page app which is served by `routes.index`.

In order to catch all other routes and route them to the index page so that your angular app can see if it matches the supplied url all you need to do is add the following line after your last route is declared:

```
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

Now you should be able to:

- navigate directly to a url served by your Angular.js app
- refresh any page without error

Answer (score 8):

This article might help:

http://jjt.io/2013/11/16/angular-html5mode-using-yeoman-generator-angular/

In a nutshell:

```
npm install --save-dev connect-modrewrite
```

Gruntfile:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    // ...
    // Modrewrite rule, connect.static(path) for each path in target's base
    middleware: function (connect, options) {
      var optBase = (typeof options.base === 'string') ? [options.base] : options.base;
      return [require('connect-modrewrite')(['!(\\..+)$ / [L]'])].concat(
        optBase.map(function(path){ return connect.static(path); }));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Route `app.get('/index/dashboard', routes.dashboard);` refers to `http://hostname/index/dashboard` whereas `when('/dashboard', { ... })` refers to `http://hostname/dashboard`.

You should correct the route: `app.get('/dashboard', routes.dashboard);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I get this 500 Express
500 Error: Failed to lookup view "dashboard" when I use the route app.get('/dashboard', routes.dashboard);

Comment: Try `when('/index/dashboard', { ... })`. You are using `html5Mode` and all your app routes should be equal to the server routes.

Comment: `app.get('/index/dashboard', routes.dashboard)` on server and `when('/index/dashboard', { ... })` on client produce a 500??? I don understand… If you navigate in brawser to `http://hostname/index/dashboard` you get a 500?

Comment: oh, wait it kind of works. Sorry, now I can't link to it but I can directly to that url but my layout template isn't working. I'll update when I get totally working and credit you. Thanks!

Comment: This is still totally hosed. Thanks for you help but there is definitely a deeper issue with this. I'm not really sure whats going on but there clearly is a some problem between node routes and angular routes.

Comment: The problem is that express can´t find dashboard view under ``/views`` directory at the ``app.render`` call:

    ``exports.dashboard = function(req, res){
        res.render('dashboard');
    };
``
That's where the 500 ``Failed to lookup view "dashboard"``comes from.
Isn't it ``app.render('partials/dashboard')``?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a pretty fast javascript solution in front and back end.

**NodeJs**

```
// set up our one route to the index.html file
    app.get('*', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
});
```

This code tells to de local/remote server where is the main html, so it could find the rest of templates.

**AngularJs**

```
// If 404 Redirect to home
$routeProvider.otherwise( { redirectTo: '/'} );
```

This is also really helpful, so never goes to a missing page.

Comment: From this `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));` what is path

Comment: @Kartheeks path is

`const path = require('path');`