# OAuth with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, oauth

I'm trying to add a social authentication to my project, which I created with Yeoman. But there is a problem with callback. It can't find my local server.

`http://localhost:9000/oauth2callback#access_token=...`

`Cannot GET /oauth2callback`

I found that this is node js issue, that mentions on stackoverflow [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700099/node-js-angular-js-cannot-get) but it doesn't work with `http://hostname/` in routes, and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request) where grunt connect module conflicts with other connect modules in Yeoman seed app (perhaps I couldn't setup it properly).

Project code [stored on github](https://github.com/zishe/angularjs_google_login) and based on [angular-oauth](https://github.com/enginous/angular-oauth) which works. [This](https://github.com/zishe/angularjs_google_login/blob/master/app/scripts/app.coffee) is routes file. The project is pretty simple.

Also I would be grateful for any help with this or more general solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on someone github files.
https://gist.github.com/zishe/6925726
Works great!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach I have taken with using subdomains, for an Angular App and Express JS (both are completely separated code, but share the same domain name).

https://gist.github.com/amitaibu/6573250